# (Gatsby) How to add overflow: hidden with an on Click event?

Tags: javascript, css, sass, gatsby

I'm having a problem with adding overflow hidden to my page in Gatsby with SASS.
can it be done with JS ?

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.scss";
import Hamburger from "hamburger-react";
import Menu from "../Menu";

export default function TopBar() {
    const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const toggleMenu = () => {
    setOpen(!isOpen);
    };

    return (
    <div className="topBar">
        <div className="topbar-container">
        <div className="topbar-container__logo">Liza Willow</div>
        <span className="topbar-container__menu-btn" onClick={toggleMenu}>
            <Hamburger size={29} rounded toggled={isOpen} toggle={setOpen} />
        </span>
        <Menu isOpen={isOpen} setOpen={setOpen} toggleMenu={toggleMenu} />
        </div>
    </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily get add a unique class name to the body tag or even apply the styles directly once the menu is open. the code will sit inside the toggleMenu function as it is already used to toggle between the menu states.

I would go with something like this:

```
  const toggleMenu = () => {
    // get the body element tag
    let body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

    // apply the styles based on menu state
    if (!isOpen) body.style.overflow = "hidden";
    else body.style.overflow = "auto";
}
```